# struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 1024 bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, integer, pyaudio

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import wave
import array
filaname=".test.wav"
wf=wave.open(filaname,"rb")
CHUNK=512*2
FORMAT=pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS=1
RATE=44100
p=pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream=p.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    output=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)
data=wf.readframes(CHUNK)
data_int=struct.unpack(str(CHUNK)+ 'B',data)
print(data_int)
```

Above is the code in which I'm trying to convert the audio bytes into integers but I'm getting a error "**data_int=struct.unpack(str(CHUNK)+ 'B',data)**

**struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 1024 bytes**"

Comment: @wwii yes. I want the data in 1024 byte chunk and unpack each chunk.

Comment: Quite a few results searching with `struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 1024 bytes site:stackoverflow.com` did you explore any of those for an answer?

Comment: `readframes` returns a bytes object, why do you need to unpack it with `struct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct.unpack` is unnecessary here. Byte strings are already indexed as integers, so `data[index]` returns an integer. If you need a mutable list if those integers, `list(data)` will return it.  `bytearray` is also a mutable version of `bytes`.

Example:

```
>>> data = b'\x01\x02\x03abc'
>>> data[0]
1
>>> list(data)
[1, 2, 3, 97, 98, 99]
>>> ba = bytearray(data)
>>> ba
bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03abc')
>>> ba[3]=5
>>> ba
bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\x05bc')
```